# In matplotlib, why is it faster to plot with thinner lines?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I stumbled across this today: it seems that it is much faster to plot lines in matplotlib if the linewidth is less than 1.0. I have only tested this on the Mac, but the effect seems very strong.

For instance, if you try this code, you will see that the data plots about 10x faster with a linewidth of 0.5 rather than a linewidth of 1.0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,10,20000)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.random(len(x))*0.1

plt.ion()
plt.show()

plt.plot(x,y,lw=0.5)
plt.draw()

plt.figure()

plt.plot(x,y,lw=1.0)
plt.draw()
```

I used this code to make a graph of the relationship between linewidth and speed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

x = np.linspace(0,10,10000)
y = np.sin(x) + np.random.random(len(x))*0.1

plt.ion()
plt.show()

linewidths = np.linspace(2,0,20)
times = []

for lw in linewidths:
    t = time.time()

    plt.plot(x,y,lw=lw)
    plt.draw()

    times.append(time.time()-t)

    plt.figure()



plt.ioff()
plt.plot(linewidths[1:],times[1:],'ro')

plt.xlabel('Linewidth (points)')
plt.ylabel('Time (seconds)')
plt.show()
```

And here is the result: [image]

Using a linewidth less than 1.0 provides a ~10x speedup, and after 1.0, the time increases linearly. I only observe this effect if the number of datapoints is large, greater than about 5000 points or so. It makes sense to me that if I ask matplotlib to display more pixels, then it might take a little longer to make the plot, but I was not expecting a huge speedup for using a slightly smaller linewidth (0.5 versus 1.0).

Can anyone explain why this occurs? I am happy to have discovered it, as it makes it much faster to display large datasets.

---

Some suggested that this might be specific to the MacOSX backend. This seems likely. If I try to save the plots in png format instead of plotting them to the screen, the times seem more randomly distributed:
[image]

Comment: Interesting. it doesn't seem to depend on aliasing, as, at least on my machine, the line aliasing is set to True even for all the linewidth.

Comment: It is very likely OS or backend dependent I think. On Mac Lion, with backend Qt4Agg, with your script I get the points scattered randomly around 0.081 seconds, so basically it is not slower with thick lines.

Comment: I would guess this has to do with Agg level details, but @flebool seems to say this isn't Agg's fault.  What backend/OS/version are you using?  (`matplotlib.get_backend()` and `matplotlib.__version__`)

Comment: Backend is MacOSX, MPL version 1.3.x. I just tried this with the Enthought python (MPL version 1.3.0) and the thicker lines seem to plot much faster. I don't know why I forget to just use the Enthought python in the first place...

Comment: but what backend were you working with before?  Also, what happens if you close the figure in the loop instead of making a new one? (and QtAgg, linux, 1.4.x about flat around .065)

Comment: @tcaswell matplotlib.get_backend() reports "MacOSX" in both cases. Also, closing the figure does not seem to make any difference. There is a noticeable different in the time that it takes for the figure window to open, so I think that it's the drawing of the lines that is making the difference. Also, I tried going through the loop both backwards and forwards in case that made a difference: it does not.

Comment: Oh, and actually switching from MPL 1.3.x to 1.3.0 didn't change the behavior. It just caused a speedup.

Comment: I've trialled with GTK, Qt and WX on my linux machine and none of them displayed this behaviour - it looks like a Mac-specific quirk. Interesting!

Comment: It does seem like it might be Mac-specific. I tried saving the files to PNG format and did not observe the same behavior (see new plot in question).

Comment: Yes, with your code I get the message: `python3.3 matplotlib_speed.py
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:412: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_num_figures`).
  max_open_warning, RuntimeWarning)`

Comment: ..and a change to linspace(0,2,10) is faster with the same behaviour. On MaxOSX with MPL 1.3.0. matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg') did not change a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone can probably replace this with a more thorough answer, but it appears that this effect is unique to the MacOSX backend, since it does not appear when saving the figures as png. The plotting time seems to also be affected by the version of Matplotlib (1.3.x versus 1.3.0). But, it seems the Mac users can enjoy a speedup for large datasets by decreasing the linewidth to a value smaller than 1.0.

Comment: Please be careful about using the macos back end and using a *Agg back end on a  mac