# Which is the fastest backend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any guidance on which backend in matplotlib is fastest? On windows and on mac.

I tried:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PS')
```

Comment: Backend for what? What're you trying to do?

Comment: @cricket_007, backend as defined here: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend I am trying to plot a plot which has several subplots and takes a long time to plot

Comment: Can't you `%timeit`?

Comment: That is actually a good question. But I think it needs some refinition. It will surely depend on whether you want to plot it to screen or save it to a file. For each case there are different possible backends to be used. @user308827 Why don't you try it out with different backends, measure the time it takes and post your findings here? That might be beneficial for others as well. Also, Mac seems to [behave a bit differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905273/in-matplotlib-why-is-it-faster-to-plot-with-thinner-lines).